# Access Amazon EC2 VPC Instance with Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have created a new EC2 VPC instance on Amazon.

When we created instance at Amazon, it was created with IP address generally know as a Public IP.

For ex: Public IP: xx.xxx.xxx.xx

And we can access our site using above public IP Address (xx.xxx.xxx.xx).

Now we need to create one another public IP address for our site.

For ex: Public IP: yy.yyy.yyy.yy

Is it possible to create multiple IP addresses? If yes, then how to do that? Let us inform with an appropriate answer.

Note that after assigning multiple addresses, our site should be accessed on any of the IP addresses assigned.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Multiple IP

EC2-Classic:
Instances support only a single private IP address and a corresponding EIP.

EC2-VPC:
Instances support multiple IP addresses, and each one can have a corresponding EIP. For more information, see Multiple Private IP Addresses http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html

Comment: There is a difference between private IP and public IP.

Comment: EIP (Elastic IP) is referred as public IP

Comment: Yes, original question has been revised to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign multiple (free of charge) public IP addresses to a single instance.

But you could assign an additional network interface at your instance and configure your system to work with two interfaces. After that you can [assign an Elastic IP to your new interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#associate_eip) ([extra costs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)).